# Is there any methods to avoid amplitude click when stop/start AKOscillator beside using Envelopes

Tags: audiokit

If I use AKOscillator only for specific purpose, should I anyway use Envelopes classes to avoide
amplitude click when I start/stop oscillator?
Or there any other more light methods?

Answer (score 1):

One "light" method is to set your parameter ramp to a non zero value, start your amplitude at zero, and then set your amplitude. Ramping is the same value for all parameters, though, so depending on if you want your frequency to change at a different ramp, you may want to change the ramp again after it has reached the amplitude you want.

Here's an example playground:

```
import AudioKitPlaygrounds
import AudioKit

let oscillator = AKOscillator(waveform: AKTable(.sine), amplitude: 0)
oscillator.rampDuration = 0.2

AudioKit.output = oscillator
try AudioKit.start()

oscillator.start()
oscillator.amplitude = 1.0

sleep(1)
oscillator.amplitude = 0
```

Comment: Hi Aurelius! As code is not fit in comment I make new answer in this thread with code and comment

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and it did not help, but I found out that this 'click' appears on the end, when oscillator stops. so if even rampDuration is 0.0, there is not 'click' at the start, the only 'click' is on the end. Here is my code (it is inside IOS app):

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var osc = AKOscillator(waveform: AKTable(.sine), amplitude: 0)

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {    //when button in App is pressed

    osc.rampDuration = 0.2
    AudioKit.output = osc
    osc.frequency = Double.random(in: 100.0...1000.0)

    try? AudioKit.start()

    osc.start()
    osc.amplitude = 0.5
    osc.rampDuration = 0.0 //to avoid frequency glide effect

    sleep(1)

    //osc.rampDuration - I tried to change rampDuration before oscillator stop, but it 
    //did not help      

    osc.stop()     //here is amplitude 'click' appears

    try? AudioKit.stop()
    }
```

So, as I supposed I have to use envelopes anyway?

Comment: Yes, if you stop an oscillator it will make a click sound. You have to stop it like I did by setting the amplitude to zero.

Comment: Yes, now I tuned a delay between setting amplitude to 0 and oscillator stop about 0.2 sec and there is not click. if delay is less - there is a click. thank you!

Comment: I also just noticed that you're starting snd stopping AudioKit within a button tap. That is a very heavy set of things to do. Instead, keep AudioKit running. Sure if you just turn off AudioKit it will not respect some internal nodes ramp duration stuff.  Its a big hammer.